# Importing Quandl library into Android

Tags: java, android, quandl

I am currently 3 months+ into programming and am trying to build an android app that takes data from Quandl.

How do I import the Quandl library into my Android project? I have tried to search for answers - they typically tell me to add the .jar file, but there is no .jar file in the Quandl library here (taken from the link below).

https://github.com/jimmoores/quandl4j

Will really appreciate it if someone posts a step by step guide for a noob beginner like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the link you have provided:

https://github.com/jimmoores/quandl4j.

Look at Quick Start section. You have four options.

1. You can download zip. There is source code inside. You should unzip this archive and then use maven to build jar file. Go to main directory, where pom.xml file is and execute `mvn install`. If build is successful then jar file should be in target directory.
2. If you are familiar with git you can clone repository and as previous crate jar with maven (`mvn install`).
3. You can use maven to add dependency to your project automatically.
4. You can use gradle, another tool that automates process of building dependency.

Generally speaking: you are new to programming, spend some time learning about maven, because this tool will help you a lot in your career.

https://maven.apache.org/

After reading this answer please remove this question, because it has a little value for community.

Comment: thanks @Luk. will do so after I thoroughly examine it. Thank you so much!